# Java Future unchecked conversion when creating future of double dimension arrays

Tags: java

The following line gives me a warning of

```java
Future<int[][]>[] futures = new Future[numWorkers];
```

Type safety: The expression of type Future[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Future<int[][]>[]

I do understand what this warning is, but I am not able to figure out the correct syntax for fixing this warning. How should I write this expression to not produce a warning?

```java
Future<int[][]>[] futures = new Future<int[][]>[numWorkers]; // BAD: This is syntax error
```

Comment: So this is an array of Futures for two-dimensional int arrays? Could you describe the nature of your data? What do you want do represent with `futures`?

Comment: You could use a List instead: `List<Future<int[][]>> futures = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Please post the exact syntax error message that you're getting